# return new instance of this, not a reference to this

Tags: java

I was messing around with the different ways Java treats variables as "values of references" from what I've read. I ended up asking myself if return values work the same way, so i wrote the following program :

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Nb firstNb = new Nb(1);
        Nb secondNb = firstNb.getNewInstance(); //secondNb.theNb == 1
        
        secondNb.changeNb();
        
        System.out.println(firstNb.theNb); //2
        System.out.println(secondNb.theNb);//2
        
        secondNb.theNb = 5;
        
        System.out.println(firstNb.theNb);//5
        System.out.println(secondNb.theNb);//5
    }
}

class Nb
{
    public int theNb;
    
    public Nb(int nb)
    {
        this.theNb = nb;
    }
    
    public Nb getNewInstance()
    {
        return(this);
    }
    
    public void changeNb()
    {
        this.theNb++;
    }
}
```

Would there be a way to return an object that is separated in memory but has the same values as the instance that returns it ? some sort of `return new this;`, not having to assign every variable of the new instance manually.

The goal would be to have the first two prints print "1" and "2" as I call `changeNb()` on the second instance and the second set of prints be "1" and "5" as I changed the value of the integer of the second instance.
The written program being an example, I'm more here by curiosity, not exactly looking for a solution for this particular program.

Comment: If your class implements [Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and overwrites [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) as public method, `return this.clone()`  would be what you are looking for.

Comment: The simplest way is to `return new Nb(theNb)`. You can also use `this.clone()` but that's strongly discouraged for various reasons.

Comment: @418cat If you do not want to call the class constructor nor a `clone` method, it is not possible to create a new object. (Well, if your class was [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html) you probably could serialize then deserialize to get a new instance, but that is really hacky and might just call your constructor anyways.)

Comment: So you want a new instance of `this` with a different value for a private variable but you don't want to use `clone()` or a constructor, and you are also describing this as 'creat[ing] an instance of `this` with the *same* values' [emphasis added]. You are contradicting yourself multiply. What led you into this conceptual prison?

Comment: @user207421 I didn't express myself with the correct terms, let's say I have a final variable that's set as the time of the creation, and I want to copy `this` with the original timestamp

Comment: Remember that a `clone()` method (or a copy constructor) would be written inside the class itself, and thus would have access to private fields. A copy constructor (but not `clone()`) would also be able to set `final` fields.

Comment: @yshavit right, thanks ! I'll probably go with that, it's helpful !

Answer (score 3):

Create a copy constructor

```
public Nb(Nb nb) {
    this.theNb = nb.theNb;
    #set every attribute, private attributes are accessible as well
}
```

now you can copy a Nb object with

```
Nb nb1 = new Nb(1);
Nb nb2 = new Nb(nb1);

nb2.changeNb(); #is now 2 and nb1.theNb is still 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

- `newInstance` just creates a copy of everything.
- Each `setter` returns the current object so other setters can be called as setters of the new object.

```
public class CopyAnInstance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       MyObj first = new MyObj(1,2,"abc", List.of("A","B","C"));
       MyObj second = first.newInstance().setA(10);
       System.out.println(first);
       System.out.println(second);
    }
}
```

prints

```
1, 2, abc, [A, B, C]
10, 2, abc, [A, B, C]
```

The class definition

```
class MyObj {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private String s;
    private List<String> list;
    
    public MyObj(int a, int b, String s, List<String> list) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.s = s;
        this.list = list;
    }
    
    public  MyObj newInstance() {
        return new MyObj(a,b,s,new ArrayList<>(list));
    }
    
    public MyObj setA(int val) {
        this.a = val;
        return this;
    }
    public MyObj setB(int val) {
        this.b = val;
        return this;
    }
    public MyObj setS(String val) {
        this.s = val;
        return this;
    }
    
    public MyObj setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%d, %d, %s, %s".formatted(a,b,s,list);
    }
}
```

**Considerations:**

- Be careful when copying hierarchical lists of mutable objects.  Each accessible and changeable object must be newly instantiated, otherwise you are passing references which can affect the source objects if their copied instances are altered.
- Immutable objects can just be passed as is.
- So can immutable lists (e.g. List.of) as long as the items themselves are immutable (per the first bullet). In spite of `List.of` being immutable and containing immutable strings I created a new mutable list.  Handling details like this are up to you.  This is just an example of one possibility.
- If your arguments to your class have primitive arrays or the arrays contain immutable objects, then cloning is a good way to copy them.

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
int[] b = a.clone(); // an exact copy of 'a' but a completely different instance.
```